# Javascript: Is there a function version of o.key / o['key']?

Tags: javascript

Given `o = { hey: 'sup' }`, is there a vanilla `function` that is equivalent to `o.hey` / `o['hey']`?

My use case:

```
a = [ 'hey', 'nm' ];
o = { hey: 'sup', nm: 'u?' };

a.map(e => o[e]);
```

I want to replace that `e => o[e]` with something like `o.get`. The use case is rather trivial, but it'd make me feel a little better to use a function rather than create a lambda.

Note: I know I could use `Map` over `Object`, but that's another question.

Comment: Did you mean `o.get`?

Comment: `const get = p => o => o[p]; a.map(get(e));`…

Comment: @Bergi, Yes I did, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's not. You should get comfortable with the lambda, which is really simple and understandable.

Of course you *can* write a helper function

```
function getPropertyIn(o) {
    return p => o[p];
}
```

and use it like `a.map(getPropertyIn(o))` but I would not recommend it for simplicity.